# assign an key value inside a sub key in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

I have an object:

```
let names = { field1: 'ton', field2: null }  // or field3 does not exist
```

and I need to insert accord to an variable elements inside names object, to

```
field='field2'
relative='brotherage'
names[field][relative] =  30;  // has no effect in my code, why ?
```

to get this:

```
 { field1: 'ton', field2: {brotherage: 30 } }
```

and add more elements to fields with this type of code:

```
field='field2'
relative='cousinage'
names[field][relative] =  20;  // has no effect in my code, why ?
```

to get this:

```
 { field1: 'ton', field2: {brotherage: 30, cousingage: 30 } }
```

what is the best methos or why i'm failing... i've tried a lot of things but i get lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a default object if the property has a falsy value or does not exists.

```js
var names = { field1: 'ton', field2: null },
    field = 'field2',
    field1 = 'field3', 
    relative = 'brotherage';
    relative1 = 'inlaw';
    
names[field] = names[field] || {};
names[field][relative] =  30;

names[field1] = names[field1] || {};
names[field1][relative1] =  40;

console.log(names);
```

Comment: elements inside object can be null or undefines too ? case field3 has no exist ? can I use the same logic for a member that does not exist?

Comment: yes, the pattern works for non existent properties as well, because the value of a not initialized property is `undefined`, a falsy value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize `names[field]` with an empty object first :

```js
let names = { field1: 'ton', field2: {} }

field='field2'
relative='brotherage'
names[field][relative] = 30

field='field2'
relative='cousinage'
names[field][relative] = 20

console.log(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `field2` field with an empty object:

```
let names = { field1: 'ton', field2: {} }
```

Answer (score 1):

> // has no effect in my code, why ?

Because `names[ "field2" ]` is `null` and you code is error'ng out as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'brotherage' of null

You need to make it first make it an object

```
names[field] = names[field] || {}; 
names[field][relative] =  30;
```

Comment: field, have already values, and relative can have too, i need to check or test values before directly to initialize, i think nina is the right answer

Comment: @DDave You are right, you need to check before assigning it directly. I have corrected it now, but I guess other experts called it out first.